# Creating Association Rule Mining Model in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, data-mining

I am creating a model in visual studio using the association rule mining. I have first created the case table and nested table from my source data. Then create a relationship in visual studio as well. Initially it was not working with the error of SQL Browser Service is not running or the analysis server is not up. Fortunately, I was able to crack it and now it was working.

Now, when I try to deploy, it is deployed but did not process and throws a lot of errors. Attached is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have changed below information and it worked and all errors were removed. It was basically permission issue.

Go to your relational database on SSMS and double click on below:
[image]

Go to user mapping and select your database and change permissions listed :
[image]

Click ok, restart SQL services and analysis services from SQL Configuration Manager and try deploying your project again